# ¿Cómo puedo visualizar el comportamiento de mi modelo detectron2 ya entrenado a través de gráficos?

Tags: machine-learning, inteligencia-artificial

espero que se encuentren muy bien. Les comento, hice el entrenamiento de la red neuronal Detectron2, descargué el archivo model_final.pth y los otros que vienen con él como metric.json y demás. El modelo responde bien pero me gustaría poder visualizar su comportamiento a través de las gráficas, podrían ser las de AP, pero no se como hacerlo, espero me puedan ayudar. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mira, yo utilicé Detectron2 para realizar Instance Segmentation, entrené el modelo por medio de Google Colab, probé su rendimiento con las imagenes de test y validación y el resultado fué positivo, descargué el model_final.pth que corresponde al modelo entrenado y lo tengo en mi PC. La pregunta parte de que quiero visualizar el comportamiento del modelo en funcion de las iteraciones por medio de graficas, para así lograr analizar y entender estadisticamente su comportamiento.